# Why the tcp socket can't read the data with C#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

```
public static byte[] StartClient(string ip, int port, byte[] message, bool needBack, out string errorMsg)
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        // Connect to a remote device.
        try
        {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

            // Create a TCP/IP  socket.
            Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.
            try
            {
                sender.Connect(remoteEP);

                // Send the data through the socket.
                int bytesSent = sender.Send(message);
                if (needBack)
                {
                    // Receive the response from the remote device.
                    int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                    byte[] array = new byte[bytesRec];
                    Array.Copy(bytes, array, bytesRec);
                    sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    sender.Close();
                    errorMsg = "";
                    return array;
                }
                else
                {
                    errorMsg = "";
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                errorMsg = string.Format("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
                return null;
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                errorMsg = string.Format("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                errorMsg = string.Format("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorMsg = string.Format("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I use the code above to send and receive tcp message from the server.but I read nothing.
I don't want a async method.I have searched some example codes, they are written like this. Is there something wrong that I didn't realized.Thanks for help.

```
public class MyTcpClient
{
    IPEndPoint _remote;
    Socket _socket;
    public bool IsStopReceive{set;get;}
    public MyTcpClient(string ip, int port)
    {
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
        _remote = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
               SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        _socket.Connect(_remote);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(obj=>{
            IsStopReceive = false;
            ReceiveMsg();
        });
    }

    public void Send(byte[] bytes) {
        _socket.Send(bytes);
    }

    private MemoryStream memoryResult;
    private void ReceiveMsg()
    {
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        while (!IsStopReceive)
        { 
            byte[] bytes=new byte[1024];
            int result = _socket.Receive(bytes);
            if (result > 0) {
                memStream.Write(bytes, 0, result);
            }
            else if (result == 0) {
                IsStopReceive = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (OnMsgReceive != null) {
            OnMsgReceive(memStream.GetBuffer());
        }
    }

    public Action<byte[]> OnMsgReceive{set;get;}
   }
```

the code above can receive the data.when I create a MyTcpClient instance,it will open a thread to receive data after connect to the target.
I use a Action to get the data after it finished.but this is async.Most important is that I don't know why I missed the data with the prev method.

Comment: Where is the server code? Is the server definitely sending a response?

Comment: I suggest Sysinternals TCPView to monitor the connection and the amount of transmitted data, and HWGroup Hercules as network terminal software to simulate the sender/receiver (it provides TCP client and server and UP endpoint, and serial port connections).

Comment: When you say "I read nothing", do you mean that your code hangs in the call to `Receive`?

Comment: yes. It hangs and waits a long time then return with a zero length array

Comment: @Klibby the server is a PCB, I can't get the server's code ,but the wireshark shows the data back. and I can receive it when I open a single thread to do the receive before the send method